# C# Convert DateTime in the CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, datetime, currentculture

How to get CurrectCulture and force converting and converting back a  DateTime in this culture.
I have tried

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(myDate , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it does't work. then I suppose that I must specify the CurrentCulture.

Comment: It may sound stupid, but isn't the current culture used by default if you don't pass in a culture explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
 var myDate = DateTime.Parse(myDate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  represents the culture used by the current thread.

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(myDate , CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Could you explain why you're not using `CurrentUICulture`?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar any difference between them

Comment: As far as I understand there actually could be. One is the info "that represents the current user interface culture used by the Resource Manager to look up culture-specific resources at run time", the other "represents the culture used by the current thread". I wonder when to use which.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar i think here `CurrentUICulture` would be fine, i am right??

Comment: I don't know! I am asking you as I am really interested. I'd probably have used `CurrentUICulture` for display as it would be coherent with the other resources, but I seriously don't know!